# Mysql Codeigniter Active Record - How do I do a where_in query and return the correct order of results?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, search, activerecord

I have a set of IDs passed in a particular order which needs to be retained.
I am querying from several left joins the data related to each ID.
The IDs are returned from a search so the order must be kept to make the results valid (otherwise it makes searching rather pointless).

My code looks something like;

```
$this->db->where_in('id', $array_of_ordered_ids);
```

For example -

```
$this->db->where_in('id', array(4,5,2,6));
```

Will return the results in order 2,4,5,6.

I'd like for it to retain the order and return the results 4,5,2,6.

Thank you,

Comment: You need to add an order by clause to tell the SQL server in which order to return the rows, `in(4,5,2,6)` will only specify which to return but not the order.

Comment: Could you give any examples using the CI's activerecord class' order_by function? Unlike the where_in function order_by does not accept an array as the second parameter and the documentation does not state much apart from the ability to order desc, asc and random.

Comment: I added an answer that shows how to do it (create a string out of the array) and which mysql function you could use. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To order the result by the order in your array, you can do the following:

```
$array_of_ordered_ids = array(4,5,2,6);
```

As you already know the order of the numbers, you can use the Mysql [`FIELD()`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 4, 5, 2, 6);
```

To create such a string, you can use [`implode`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/implode):

```
$order = sprintf('FIELD(id, %s)', implode(', ', $array_of_ordered_ids));
```

Give it a try:

```
$array_of_ordered_ids = array(4,5,2,6);
$this->db->where_in('id', $array_of_ordered_ids);
$order = sprintf('FIELD(id, %s)', implode(', ', $array_of_ordered_ids));
$this->db->order_by($order);
```

Comment: Thanks, in theory the answer should be correct but thanks to your advice it helped me to pinpoint the actual issue.
For reference what was going wrong was that the codeigniter order_by surrounds every input with a backtick. Thus any references to IDs then got interpreted as column names! Looks like i'll have to write up the SQL myself. Thanks Hakre.

Comment: Maybe there is another parameter that prevents CI doing that, some of the active record functions have it, but I fear order_by has not. So maybe it helps you to write your SQL, you can create the `IN()` statement similarly.

Comment: I went through the active record source code in my application and it seems it simply is just a bug. I wrote the SQL in a few minutes and it is all working now!

Comment: but is making ORDER BY FIELD(id, \`4\`,\`5\`, \`2\`, \`6\`); how can i remove \` from query

Answer (score 5):

As all answers I found on SO where just semi correct but all gave good hints I implemented successfully the code to retrieve set of rows correct ordered by the order in given array.

To Produce a sql like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (`product`) WHERE `id` IN (2, 34, 234) 
ORDER BY FIELD(`id`, 2, 34, 234)
```

use this code, while $ids contains the array (2, 34, 234).

```
// select from ... 
$this->db->where_in('id',$ids);
$this->db->_protect_identifiers = FALSE; // stop CI adding backticks
$order = sprintf('FIELD(id, %s)', implode(', ', $ids));
$this->db->order_by($order);
$this->db->_protect_identifiers = TRUE; // switch on again for security reasons
// get...
```

see also here: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/137157/#1058666

Answer (score 0):

Thank for biggest solution.

```
 $orde_num_string = implode(",",$order_num);
            $this->db->where_in("cir_order.order_num",$order_num);
            $this->db->_protect_identifiers = FALSE;
            $this ->db->order_by("FIELD(cir_order.order_num, $orde_num_string)");
            $this->db->_protect_identifiers = TRUE;
```