# Order Results with PHP array in Code Igniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I have an array of numbers in PHP that represent primary keys("pro_id") in my DB that I send through my model in CodeIgniter to get only 10 specific rows.

This numbers might change but for now I'll use this to demonstrate my point.

This is the array:

```
Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 3 [2] => 8 [3] => 12 [4] => 30 [5] => 29 [6] => 26 [7] => 28 [8] => 4 [9] => 7 )
```

And this is the model I send it through:

```
public function get_flores_home($array_select) {
    $this->db->where_in('pro_id', $array_select);
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

**However, I would like to have my results sorted by the same order the array was in.**

This is the result I'm currently getting:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [pro_id] => 3[pro_nombre] => Ashley[pro_descripcion] => 24RosasBaseDeCerámica[pro_precio] => 480[pro_es_disponible] => 1[pro_imagen] => 0edb4 - ashley . jpg
    ) [1] => Array(
        [pro_id] => 4[pro_nombre] => Abril[pro_descripcion] => 6RosasRojas, LilisBlancas, Alstroemerias[pro_precio] => 320[pro_es_disponible] => 1[pro_imagen] => 3f9f1 - abril . jpg
    ) [2] => Array(
        [pro_id] => 5[pro_nombre] => Amira[pro_descripcion] => 12Rosas . Alstroemerias . MallaBlanca . Moño . [pro_precio] => 280[pro_es_disponible] => 1[pro_imagen] => 81e6c - amira . jpg
    ) [3] => Array(
        [pro_id] => 7[pro_nombre] => Betty[pro_descripcion] => 24Rosas . Alcatraces . Alstroemerias . Moño[pro_precio] => 650[pro_es_disponible] => 1[pro_imagen] => 57219 - betty . jpg
    ) [4] => Array(
        [pro_id] => 8[pro_nombre] => Brittany[pro_descripcion] => 24RosasRojas . MallaElegante . Moño[pro_precio] => 450[pro_es_disponible] => 1[pro_imagen] => 942cf - brittany . jpg
    ) [5] => Array(
        [pro_id] => 12[pro_nombre] => Diana[pro_descripcion] => 24Rosas . LilisBlancas . BaseDeCeramica . [pro_precio] => 490[pro_es_disponible] => 1[pro_imagen] => a9bb8 - diana . jpg
    ) [6] => Array(
        [pro_id] => 26[pro_nombre] => Katy[pro_descripcion] => 48Rosas . LilisAmarillas . Lisianthusmorado . CampanitaDeIrlanda . [pro_precio] => 1200[pro_es_disponible] => 1[pro_imagen] => 478a6 - katy . jpg
    ) [7] => Array(
        [pro_id] => 28[pro_nombre] => Lucia[pro_descripcion] => 24Rosas . 10Tulipanes . CampanitaDeIrlanda . Stargazer . BaseDeCeramica . [pro_precio] => 900[pro_es_disponible] => 1[pro_imagen] => f0829 - lucia . jpg
    ) [8] => Array(
        [pro_id] => 29[pro_nombre] => Magdalena[pro_descripcion] => 24Rosas . LilisBlancas . BaseDeCeramica . [pro_precio] => 590[pro_es_disponible] => 1[pro_imagen] => 29403 - magdalena . jpg
    ) [9] => Array(
        [pro_id] => 30[pro_nombre] => Marisol[pro_descripcion] => 24Rosas . 5Lilis . Alstroemerias . Canasta . [pro_precio] => 750[pro_es_disponible] => 1[pro_imagen] => 1eb20 - marisol . jpg
    )
)
```

This is the array I want my result to be sorted like:

```
Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 3 [2] => 8 [3] => 12 [4] => 30 [5] => 29 [6] => 26 [7] => 28 [8] => 4 [9] => 7 )
```

This is the Result in the desired order:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [pro_id] => 5[pro_nombre] => Amira[pro_descripcion] => 12Rosas . Alstroemerias . MallaBlanca . Moño . [pro_precio] => 280[pro_es_disponible] => 1[pro_imagen] => 81e6c - amira . jpg
    ) [1] => Array(
        [pro_id] => 3[pro_nombre] => Ashley[pro_descripcion] => 24RosasBaseDeCerámica[pro_precio] => 480[pro_es_disponible] => 1[pro_imagen] => 0edb4 - ashley . jpg
    ) [2] => Array(
        [pro_id] => 8[pro_nombre] => Brittany[pro_descripcion] => 24RosasRojas . MallaElegante . Moño[pro_precio] => 450[pro_es_disponible] => 1[pro_imagen] => 942cf - brittany . jpg
    ) [3] => Array(
        [pro_id] => 12[pro_nombre] => Diana[pro_descripcion] => 24Rosas . LilisBlancas . BaseDeCeramica . [pro_precio] => 490[pro_es_disponible] => 1[pro_imagen] => a9bb8 - diana . jpg
    ) [4] => Array(
        [pro_id] => 30[pro_nombre] => Marisol[pro_descripcion] => 24Rosas . 5Lilis . Alstroemerias . Canasta . [pro_precio] => 750[pro_es_disponible] => 1[pro_imagen] => 1eb20 - marisol . jpg
    ) [5] => Array(
        [pro_id] => 29[pro_nombre] => Magdalena[pro_descripcion] => 24Rosas . LilisBlancas . BaseDeCeramica . [pro_precio] => 590[pro_es_disponible] => 1[pro_imagen] => 29403 - magdalena . jpg
    ) [6] => Array(
        [pro_id] => 26[pro_nombre] => Katy[pro_descripcion] => 48Rosas . LilisAmarillas . Lisianthusmorado . CampanitaDeIrlanda . [pro_precio] => 1200[pro_es_disponible] => 1[pro_imagen] => 478a6 - katy . jpg
    ) [7] => Array(
        [pro_id] => 28[pro_nombre] => Lucia[pro_descripcion] => 24Rosas . 10Tulipanes . CampanitaDeIrlanda . Stargazer . BaseDeCeramica . [pro_precio] => 900[pro_es_disponible] => 1[pro_imagen] => f0829 - lucia . jpg
    ) [8] => Array(
        [pro_id] => 4[pro_nombre] => Abril[pro_descripcion] => 6RosasRojas, LilisBlancas, Alstroemerias[pro_precio] => 320[pro_es_disponible] => 1[pro_imagen] => 3f9f1 - abril . jpg
    ) [9] => Array(
        [pro_id] => 7[pro_nombre] => Betty[pro_descripcion] => 24Rosas . Alcatraces . Alstroemerias . Moño[pro_precio] => 650[pro_es_disponible] => 1[pro_imagen] => 57219 - betty . jpg
    )
)
```

As you can see, the order is now based on the same array I used in the "where_in" method. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort an Array by keys based on another Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348410/sort-an-array-by-keys-based-on-another-array)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem and related to my curiosity - why do you want result ordered by the input array? What is the problem which it would solve?

Comment: Spartan, I saw that question but can't get the same results.

Comment: N.B. I want to display them in the desired order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't know how to use CodeIgniter, but this is what you do if you want to order by some custom order such as yours:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE id IN 
(5, 3, 8, 12, 30, 29, 26, 28, 4, 7) 
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 5, 3, 8, 12, 30, 29, 26, 28, 4, 7)
```

Now, if you know how to adjust this in CodeIgniter so it produces a query like this - your problem is solved via MySQL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443284/mysql-codeigniter-active-record-how-do-i-do-a-where-in-query-and-return-the-co

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a small data set, either in your controller manipulate the arrays, or do it in your view if you want to. Just pass both the order array as $order and the result set as $results to the view:

```
foreach ($order as $wantedID) {
    foreach ($results as $result) {
       if($result['id'] == $wantedID) {
          // output your result
          ...
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->where_in('id',$arrayIds);
$arrayList = implode(',',$arrayIds);
$this->db->order_by('FIELD(id,'.$arrayList.")");
```